# ASM in VS Code via the GNU Assembler Language Support Package

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, x86, gnu, gnu-assembler

I am trying to learn Assembly, and my IDE of choice is VS Code. I installed this [GNU package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=basdp.language-gas-x86) in the VS Code marketplace to try and be able to use Assembler within VS Code, and it keeps giving me this error whenever I try to run the code: `You don't have an extension for debugging 'GAS/AT&T x86/x64'.` What should I do to bypass this error? I am on a Windows machine trying to use x86 ASM. I am not very knowledgeable about this subject (hence, why I am trying to learn it) so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: If you're running Windows, regular Visual Studio may be better for this.

Comment: @rcgldr: Probably only if you want to learn MASM syntax, rather than the free/portable NASM or GAS assemblers.  (I'd recommend NASM; it has the most clear and thus beginner-friendly error messages, and the least amount of weird stuff.  And clean, consistent syntax, e.g. a memory operand *always* has `[]`, otherwise you never have `[]`.  Again unlike MASM and GAS.)

Comment: @rcgldr: Sure, I'm not saying people should switch if they already know an assembler.  I'm talking about what to recommend to beginners who are making a fresh start with asm. NASM is an excellent assembler for "power users" as well as being clean and without weird stuff, so it's fully viable to just learn NASM and then see the weird stuff in other syntaxes as warts.

Comment: @rcgldr: I hope not, that's exactly the kind of over-complicated stuff that is not helpful for beginners.  They can maybe be useful *if* you understand how they assemble, but it seems to me it would be confusing for beginners to have those macros as well as doing it manually with cmp/jcc, like maybe not understanding that at the machine level, there are only compares and branches, not structured programming.  My understanding is that they made some sense when things were written in asm by default on old cramped machines, vs. now you only write in asm for performance / to learn the machine.

Comment: @rcgldr: That sounds exactly like the kind of case I was thinking of, where some code is written in asm but not for optimization reasons.  These days you'd just write in C or C++ and use a compiler, if you don't want to bother hand-optimizing, and maintainability is more important than every cycle of performance / byte of code-size.  Those `.if` directives usually make it hard to branch on FLAGS that were already set anyway by an instruction like `sub` or `add`.  If you're trying to learn how to think in asm / how the machine works, those directives are unhelpful (except look at dissassembly)

Comment: @rcgldr: Right sure; my point was that if you get in the habit of using `.if`, you might end up writing `.if eax != 0` instead of `je` even if the previous instruction already set FLAGS in a useful way.  And you might not look at putting an unlikely `if` or `else` block out-of-line, after the `ret`, so the fast path has zero taken branches.  (And if optimizations like that don't matter, normally you can use C, so there's not much use-case for `.if` / `.else`, or especially `.while`.  With only minor effort, many loops can have just a jcc at the bottom, if they always run at least 1 iteration.)

Comment: @rcgldr: How would you know how much speed you could have gained from possible optimizations you would have noticed if you were doing the branching manually?  Did you have more optimized versions of inner loops and so on, and discarded them after finding the benefit wasn't measurable?  If so, that's interesting.  I assume it helps to know how they work to use them efficiently.  IDK whether early 386 would be more or less sensitive to branch-layout than modern x86.  Perhaps more, since each insn has to exec one at a time, so extra jmp over the .else costs more? And insn prefetch buffer flush.

Comment: @PeterCordes - deleted prior comments. The only time I used those dot directives was when 386 first came out for that one project, where the usage was due to their standards, not for an actual need. Note that the 64 bit version of MASM, ML64.EXE, doesn't support  those dot directives. Getting back on point, I'm wondering about the popularity of the various tool sets. My impression is that for Windows, Visual Studio is the most popular.